# Notifying myself thtat my webapp/website is down (Nginx environment)

Tags: ubuntu, email, monitoring, webserver

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 xenial Nginx server environment with `postfix` and a few webapps under `/var/www/html`.

How could I notify myself by my an email sent to my personal Gmail account, **if** my site is down?

The desired state is that if the webpages or at least in homepage, doesn't give https status 200 (OK), I'll get daily email, **per each day** the problem wasn't taken care off.

For example, each day I'll get:

> Hello, your site domain.tld is down. Please fix it.

Comment: monit or wget or curl or at enterprise level for several servers, Nagios.

Comment: This is a cat with many many many skins, some of which resemble `cron` attached to a shell script, Nagios, Splunk, monit, NOCOL/SNIPS, and myriad other tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are literally dozens of ways you can do this.

The most basic possible would be to call `wget` or `curl` from a daily cron job and check their exit code (if they can't download the page, they'll return a non-zero exit code), then use that to trigger an e-mail.  While this approach has a few issues (for example, both `wget` and `curl` follow redirects, so it will also succeed for pretty much any 3xx code provided that it points to an accessible page).

A step up from that is a tool like [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/), which has the added bonus that you can have it watch your web-server process and let you know if that stops running, and do all kinds of other useful checks (including allowing for mostly arbitrary scripted network service checks, checking network interface status, etc).  This is probably the simplest option on most single servers.

If you've got a bunch of servers, you might look instead at something like [nagios](https://www.nagios.org/), which is designed for handling network-wide sanity checks.

Keep in mind also however that pretty much regardless of which option you go with, you're probably going to need to run a local mail server to forward messages to your gmail account (though this is really easy to do provided you're not using a hosting service that blocks outbound SMTP connections).

Comment: Thanks. Mail server? WordPress contact forms pass data to my personal Gmail account without me ever installed `postfix` (at least, thus I recall).

Comment: I'm not quite sure how WordPress handles things, but it's probably not going direct to your GMail account (most likely, WordPress is talking SMTP to Google's mail servers, which are then delivering things to your account).  While it's technically possible to do this with tools like Monit, it requires some potentially complicated DNS set up that isn't well supported by most DNS providers.  If you've got WordPress working though, you may be able to point monit straight at the Google SMTP servers and it will just work.